# How to change \nomrefeqpage format for nomencl

Tags: nomenclature

I am using `nomencl` to list my nomenclature. The command `\nomrefeqpage` will give an entry like,

```
  ... see equation (1.1.1), page 3.
```

Because by my convention, a number with parenthesis like (1.1.1) refers an equation, is it possible to remove the word "equation"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant part is set by `\eqdeclaration`, which by default is (in english):

```
\def\eqdeclaration#1{, see equation\nobreakspace(#1)}
```

So change it with

```
\renewcommand{\eqdeclaration}[1]{, see~(#1)}
```

and be done.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks a lot! :-)